# How do I hyperlink .oam-Animations Muse?

Tags: website-design, animation, css, adobe-muse

I have an .oam Animation made in Adobe Edge embedded in Adobe Muse.

It animates on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` using JavaScript.

How can I hyperlink it using Adobe Muse. I want to use HTML so the link keeps working when JS is disabled.

The animation stops working when I place a hyperlinked box over it

Is there any way I can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Nest the animation inside a text box with the link.

Comment: I'm able to nest the animation into it but i am not able to hyperlink it